# Rendering Checkbox based on value

Tags: apex, pageblocktable

[image: Required view]

Hi,

I have a requirement where i have to show page block table with 2 columns. 1st with Name of contacts and 2nd column with a checkbox which are disable. I have 3 objects contacts,application and verifier. Verifier is a juction object b/w contact and application. I want the checkbox in 2nd column to be checked if contact is a verifier.

Comment: is there any reason why you dont only render 'verifier' contacts and label that table accordingly?

Comment: Hi Seb, I want have list of all contacts in a table and check who all are verifiers. This would just be a readonly view. Informative purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now. Used input checkbox with checked and disable property

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `apex:inputCheckbox`. 
Generally if you reference a checkbox `value` attribute with an objects boolean fields the checkbox will be selected or deselected automatically depending on the fields value. There is also a `disabled` attribute which will disable users from clicking it on/off.

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!YourObject.BooleanField__c}" disabled="true"/>
```

Additionally you can use an attribute `selected` to manually specify whether the checkbox is selected or not:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!SomeVariable}"
                    selected="true"
                    disabled="true"/>
```

And it is possible to use a formula within a `selected` attribute:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!SomeVariable}"
                    selected="{!IF(YourObject.Contact.IsVerifier__c = 'yes', true, false)}"
                    disabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Or you could render an `<input type="checkbox" checked disabled/>` (or take out checked if it isn't). Rendering regular HTML directly instead of "wasting" an `inputCheckbox` would be advisable here.

Comment: @sfdcfox Well, then it would be even better to show just an icon like this `<img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif">`

Comment: None of this is working out for me. I will try to explain the logic. I have created a list of contact lstcontact=[select id,name,(SELECT Id,Name,contact__c FROM Verifiers__r) from contact]

Comment: <apex:pageblocktable value="{!lstContact}" var="Con">
<apex:column headerValue="Contact Name">
 <apex:outputField value="{!Con.Full_Name__c}" />
</apex:column>
 <apex:column headerValue="Verifier">
<apex:repeat var="verifier" value="{!Con.Verifiers__r}">
 <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!verifier.Name}" disabled="True" selected="{!IF(ISNULL(verifier.Name),false,true)}" />         
</apex:repeat>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageblocktable>

Comment: @TestNS The `verifier.Name` is never NULL. You need to understand that if the `Verifiers__r` list is not empty then all the entries from it are Verifiers of the corresponding contact.

Comment: Then how do i get the checkbox value to checked if contact is verifier????

Comment: The code that i have shared gives me output as.... 1st column consist of 3 contacts and in 2nd column i am able to see checkbox only where the contact is verifier but its not checked.

Comment: Its working nowwww... Used <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"/>

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.